# Why was function overloading added to C++?

Tags: c++, c, overloading

I have a C background. I was just wondering why was function overloading added to C++? C doesn't have function overloading but C++ does, what was the need for it?

What went across the mind of the language designer at that time?

Comment: One could ask : why, oh, why, isn't function overloading in C ? It would make my life easier...

Comment: @Raveline: two words; name mangling. The shared object developer's nightmare.

Comment: @roe: +1 Name mangling gives the clue as to the problems.  Function overloading is really a way of having two different functions with the same name.

Comment: <Vote to keep open>.  It's a design choice with positive and negative consequences; there's not much point arguing over whether the net effect is positive or negative, but there is value in seeing the reasons themselves.

Comment: Btw, C99 has type generic macro.tgmath.h

Comment: @Nyan: That's not even remotely the same as a good template or overload.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It increases maintainability. If you have a type T and you call a function with it, then you need to change T, if the function has been overloaded for the new T then you can recompile instantly. In C you would have to go back and dig through all the call sites and change the function called. Take sqrt(). If you want to sqrt() a float, then you have to change to sqrtf().

Not just that, but the volume and complexity of C++'s type system is far more than in C, and having to have separate function names for every possible overload would quickly exhaust the reasonable pool of names for functions that serve the same purpose but take different arguments, because now there's a lot more arguments to take.

For example, compare the C and C++ string libraries. The C string library offers one method to append to a string - strcat(). C++'s std::string::append has eight overloads. What do you want to call them? append_a, append_b, etc? That's ridiculous- they all serve the same function, just in different ways.

Edit: It *is* actually worth mentioning that `append` is a really bad example, many of the C++ string overloads are very redundant. However, this is more general case than that and not *all* of those overloads redundant.

Comment: Overloading plugs some holes in the C type system, too, such as `strchr`. Having a single name for it is so desirable that C doesn't even *have* a const-correct version. Const-safety clearly is considered less important than being able to use the same name (`strchr`) regardless of the type of the argument. To me this is a good case that if you like const enough to put it in your type system, you really should like overloading even more.

Comment: @mattdm: sqrtf() was added for a reason. That reason is nothing to do with the advantages of overloading, which is that it's easier to maintain a sqrt() call when you don't have to change the call site if you change a typedef from double to float. Also, I don't even know what you're talking about with operator overloading, that's not even part of the question. Function overload resolution is not a guess, it's a deterministic and easily controlled process. If you have a float but want to call the double sqrt(), you can cast. It's that simple.

Comment: I mistyped operator for function for no good reason. Too late to edit so I'm going to delete and repost.

Comment: `sqrt()` vs `sqrtf()` is actually a bad example. The standard sqrt() function takes (and-returns) a double-precision floating point number, and so works just fine with single-precisions floats. The `sqrtf()` function was added so that one can intentionally choose to use single-precision floating point math, which may be faster on some hardware. Function overloading can't (or at least *shouldn't*!) guess if you want precision or speed based on the input type. That would have to be either a separate parameter or another function anyway. – mattdm 22 mins ago

Comment: @DeadMG: yes, sqrtf() was added for a reason, and that reason is the one I gave. I understand that overload resolution is deterministic; that's the point. Casting does not solve the problem elegantly, because in most cases one wants the square root of a single-precision float to be calculated in double-precision, and one shouldn't have to up-cast just to request that the function work that way.

Comment: @mattdm: Agree with you that `sqrtf()` is a bad example.  A better example would be functions for serialising and deserialising objects. In this case, you want the behaviour to be type-agnostic: if you change `int x;` to `long x;`, ideally you don't want to have to change every call to `serialise(x)`.

Comment: All of these examples are arguments for **generic programming**, not overloading. In each case you expect the function with the same name but different types to do the same thing, just on a different type. A good system of generic programming, like templates, encourages or partially enforces this. Function overloading makes it too easy to make the same-named function do completely different things on different types (think of the `<<` operator...) which is counter-intuitive and harmful.

Comment: @R: Function overloading is a type of generic programming. Templates are just an example of being generic in types (and specific non-type parameters), you can't use a template to replace the overloads of append. operator<< is an excellent example of function overloading, because it's easily extensible. If you don't know whether you're using << on an int or on a stream, you've got bigger problems. @mattdm: If you want to change the precision of your float, you cast. That's how everything works- why not function calls?

Comment: @DeadMG: if I pass an integer to the function, should I expect the square root to be computed using integer math and return an integer?

Comment: @mattdm: It's not going to make sense for sqrt to take any type. That's not even remotely close to the point of function overloading. It does, however, make sense for sqrt to take a float or a double.

Answer (score 22):

One good reason, in addition to what DeadMG said, is that if you're writing a template function which e.g. calls `sqrt`, then you need a *generic* way of calling `sqrt` -- it would be very difficult if you had to try and somehow vary the name to `sqrtf`, `sqrtd`, etc., depending on the type of the template parameter. Overloading solves this problem, because then you just write `sqrt` and let the compiler figure out which overload it should be using:

```
template <typename T>
T sqrt_plus_one(T t) // contrived example
{
  return sqrt(t) + 1;
}
```

Comment: If you are going to use templating you might as well template `sqrt()` to and then you don't need overloading.

Comment: @JeremyP: templates are a form of overloading, and specialization has some surprising properties in the case of functions, to the extent that partial template function specialization was considered *worse than not having it*, and hence not permitted in C++03. To restrict overloading so that template specialization was the only form of it, you would have to solve those problems (I can't remember the details, but feel free to propose a fix...)

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Actually I think @JeremyP has a point there -- I don't think using templates throughout + some form of specialisation would necessarily be less powerful.  I'd be interested to hear concrete reasons why this approach was felt to be horrible.  (Even though it's moot because the language already had overloading when templates were being considered, so they would hardly have elected to remove it.)

Comment: @j_random_hacker: This might help (I haven't had a chance to read it through fully, but it looks like the right sort of thing) -- http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm.

Comment: @sgolodetz: Thanks, it's an excellent article (as are all of Sutter's) but not actually relevant here -- basically it says that in C++ today, it's possible to *totally* specialise a function template (which is *not* overloading), although that doesn't do what most people expect because it can be unclear *which* function template you're actually specialising.  What I'm interested in is why the wise old C++ designers decided not to allow *partial* specialisation of function templates (it is allowed for classes) but allow overloading of them instead.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: well, ignoring niggles in templates, and supposing they do everything overloading does, we're left arguing what the *syntax* should be (and whether we call it "overloading" or "specialization"). Since the niggles exist, we have two mechanisms for achieving the aim of the game, which is different functions with the same name. Three if you count ADL separately. Most arguments against overloading are of form, "you shouldn't have different functions of the same name", so JeremyP would have to speak for himself why he prefers specialization to overloading.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: What I'd like to know is what those niggles are!  But even without knowing that, there is one difference that I can make out between partial specialisation of templates and overloading: if we had only the former (which I believe is what JeremyP is advocating), the implication would be that non-template functions never overload -- and that would simplify the language, because as soon as you saw a non-template declaration for a function `foo()`, you would know that every call `foo()` is calling that exact function.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: Not to question SO, but you might get more joy from one of the C++ newsgroups (comp.lang.c++ or comp.lang.c++.moderated) if you want a detailed discussion of the issues here. The format of Usenet (thread-based, rather than Q/A-based) lends itself better to detailed discussion of things like this, and there are a lot of C++ experts who hang out there but not here.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: by "niggles" I meant the things currently in the way, such as no partial specialization and no default template parameters on function templates. I agree with you it'd be informative to know what motivates the niggles: if the only motivation was, "those features wouldn't play well with overloading", then perhaps the way was for a brief period clear for C++ to ditch what it calls overloading in favour of something else (that is still a kind of overloading), at least for free functions.

Comment: I'll admit that overloading makes template programming easier, but it can't be the reason that overloading was added to C++. As overloading was implemented in the first C++ compilers, long before templates.

Answer (score 15):

Would you prefer "selecting" one among **abs/labs/llabs/fabs/fabsf/fabsl** Or just **abs()**?

Obviously, **abs()**.

So **function overloading is a relief for programmers**, most of the time, beside other advantages.

Comment: Your argument is an argument for templates/generic programming, not for overloading.

Comment: @R, why are the two arguments mutually exclusive?  Different answers for the same problems.   That's like saying a minivan is not an answer for big families because SUVs exist.

Comment: @R....not really. You can use the same argument for templates also, but it doesn't mean that it's exclusively for that. :-)

Answer (score 12):

You could get the answer straight from the horse's mouth: [The Design and Evolution of C++](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/dne.html) by Bjarne Stroustrup devotes an entire chapter to overloading, its history, evolution, design tradeoffs and decisions.

I won't recount the story here, but will mention a couple of interesting historical facts:

- operator and function overloading are closely related;
- in early C++ there used to be a special keyword (`overload`) that had to be used to declare an identifier as overloaded;
- function overloading requires type-safe linking (i.e. name mangling); when first implemented, it helped discover a surprising number of link-time errors in existing C and C++ code (to quote Stroustrup, it was like "running `lint` on a C program for the first time -- somewhat embarrassing".)

Answer (score 3):

Try to come up with a comfortable way to construct objects if it weren't for function overloading.

```
std::string foo = "bar";
std::vector< std::string > myStringVector;
myStringVector.push_back( std::string() );
myStringVector.push_back( std::string( "hello" ) );
myStringVector.push_back( std::string( foo ) );
```

A nonsense example, of course, but it illustrates the point.

Another point would be template programming. You could not come up with generic templates if you had to have a different function name for each parameter type.

Comment: This isn't a strong argument, because there's no fundamental reason why constructors need to have the same name as their class.  It's possible to imagine a world in which a constructor is just a method labeled with `ctor` (a method type modifier like `inline` that I just made up) and that returns an instance of the class.  In this world, overloading would not be necessary for constructing objects in different ways.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: Yes, but would it be *convenient* to call `ctor new_empty_string()` and `ctor new_string_from_char_pointer()` and `ctor new_string_from_string`?

Comment: Not especially :) But, no more inconvenient than doing any non-construction thing to the object (e.g. printing it, or adding 1 to it) without overloading.  (My point is just that object construction is not a case deserving of special pleading.)

Comment: @j_random_hacker: I just picked it as the most general case. Since you named them (although they were not focus of the question), overloading `operator<<()` or `operator++()` are other nice-to-have's.

Answer (score 0):

Using polymorphism , we can design a family of functions with same function name but with different argument list . The function would perform different operations depending on the arguments list in the function call.

Comment: @DevSolar: that's not correct, polymorphism is not to be reduced to "inclusion polymorphism" (i.e. method overriding and subtyping). Method/function overloading is also a kind of polymorphism, namely "ad-hoc polymorphism".

Comment: @Luc Touraille: I stand corrected. It seems that OOP (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming) and functional programming (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_polymorphism) differ in their definition of "polymorphism", with the latter having a much wider scope in which the term is being applied. I'd take back the downvote, but it's locked until edited. :-/ I apologize.