# why overload keyword removed from C++?

Tags: c++, overloading

I was reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314040/why-was-function-overloading-added-to-c/4314090#4314090). The answer given by @NPE talks about interesting historical facts & says that,

- **In early C++ there used to be a special keyword (overload) that had
  to be used to declare an identifier as overloaded;**

So, What is the reason behind removal of **overload** keyword? I don't have `Design and Evolution of C++` by Stroustrup. What's wrong with overload keyword?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Stroustrup mentions in D&E 11.2.4 "The `overload` Keyword" that the `overload` keyword causes troubles when "merging" (or using) two libraries which both used the same function name (without namespaces*). For example, `sqrt` in the C header `math.h` versus the `sqrt(complex)` from the C++ `complex` header. If one of them declared the function as *overloadable*, but the other did not, you had to include the headers in such an order that overloading was enabled before it occurred:

```
// #include <complex>
overload sqrt;
complex sqrt(complex);

// #include <math.h>
double sqrt(double);   // fine

// ---------------------------

// #include <math.h>
double sqrt(double);

// #include <complex>
overload sqrt;         // ERROR: cannot allow overloading
                       //        of an already declared function
complex sqrt(complex);
```

The possible workarounds are "unmanageable in all but the simplest cases".

(*) The `overload` keyword was made obsolete with CFront 2.0, released in 1989. Namespaces were introduced into the standardization proposal in 1993.

The original intent of the keyword was to deal with two fears:

> 1. Concern that undetected ambiguities could occur.
> 2. Concern that a program could not properly be linked unless the programmer explicitly declared which functions were supposed to be
>      overloaded.
>
> The former fear proved largely groundless. The few problems found in actual use are dealt with by the order-independent overloading resolution rules. The latter fear proved to have no basis in a general problem with C separate compilation rules that had nothing to do with overloading.

Comment: Please buy/borrow/read D&E. It's really a great book, with many enlightening insights.

Comment: @PravasiMeet It's a C library. I think adding something like `#ifdef __cplusplus /*newline*/ overload sqrt; /*newline*/ #endif` might be considered one of those "unmanageable" workarounds, or impossible if the external library header may not be changed

Comment: please explain what do you mean to say exactly by writing "impossible if the external library header may not be changed" ?

Comment: @PravasiMeet If you may not change `math.h`, e.g. because it's a system header and the code must compile on many different platforms, then it's (literally) impossible to add `overload sqrt;` to it.

Comment: @dyp: That's actually a stubborn mistake on Unix/Linux, to think that `<math.h>` must be the system header. This is generally a very bad idea. Headers should be part of the compiler implementation. Of course, if the OS offers a premade `sqrt`, you'd want to use that as an implementor. That doesn't imply you should blindly expose every function.

Comment: @PravasiMeet I do not know the exact semantics of the `overload` keyword, however I conclude from D&E that you cannot mark an already declared name as overloadable, you must declare it as overloadable before its *first* declaration (i.e., before the first declaration of a function named `sqrt`).

Comment: Okay, it was removed for global-namespace conflict reasons, but please someone add overload-keyword back to C++, but only to classes just like `override`-keyword is limited to be used only in class/struct scope,

Comment: I have a sub-class which needs to overload many methods of parent-class, to track something, but the parent-class is from a 3rd-party library which can change method-signatures anytime, hence I need to somehow cause a compile-error once any of the overloads no-longer-overloads-parent. How to do that when overload-keyword does not exist? and that for many-many methods?

Comment: I just need said error, and there is no need for thousands of warnings, which say: "method does overload, but without overload-keyword being used (add overload to method declaration)."